# parse a string with VBA on EXCEL

Tags: regex, excel, vba, parsing

I'm trying to analyse a text file imported in an excel tab.

The first column is a text code used to represent the timeline of operations and I would tike to convert this text code into a number of seconds.

Text codes can be formated like this :

```
5,9h180s            ->  21420s
10min               ->  600s
3,4h5min30s         ->  12570s
...
```

My idea is to extract the values with a regex a use them later in a function, but I don't know VBA very good.

**Is there a function in EXCEL VBA to perform regular expressions on a string and extract data from it ?**

**Do you have an example of a such function ?**

Comment: I've reopened this question because I found it interesting and need a little practise on my [tag:regex] patterns. I won't say that the profile in question had nothing to do with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a few attempts at the various combinations (and some of my own imagination) I decided that truncating the time value string at the first letter of the unit would allow me to use that **h** / **m** / **s** as the *last character* in the [regex](/questions/tagged/regex) [.Pattern property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms974570.aspx). This pre-regex prepping gave me the best results.

In a standard module code sheet as,

```
Function howManySeconds(strTM As String) As Long
    Dim s As Long, tmp As String
    Dim rgx As Object, cmat As Object
    Dim x As Long, vPTTRNs As Variant

    Set rgx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    vPTTRNs = Array("[0-9,\.,\s]{1,9}×$", _
                    "h", 3600, "m", 60, "s", 1)

    With rgx
        .Global = True
        .IgnoreCase = True

        For x = LBound(vPTTRNs) + 1 To UBound(vPTTRNs) Step 2
            If CBool(InStr(1, LCase(strTM), vPTTRNs(x), vbTextCompare)) Then
                tmp = Replace(Replace(Replace(LCase(strTM), _
                                        "seconds", "s"), "secs", "s"), _
                                        Chr(44), Chr(46))
                tmp = Replace(Replace(Left(tmp, InStrRev(strTM, vPTTRNs(x), -1, vbTextCompare)), _
                                        Chr(44), Chr(46)), Chr(32), vbNullString)
                .Pattern = Replace(vPTTRNs(LBound(vPTTRNs)), Chr(215), vPTTRNs(x))
                Set cmat = .Execute(tmp)
                If CBool(cmat.Count) Then
                    s = s + CLng(CDbl(Replace(cmat.Item(0), vPTTRNs(x), vbNullString)) * vPTTRNs(x + 1))
                End If
            End If
        Next x

    End With

    howManySeconds = s

    Set rgx = Nothing
End Function
```

Use like any native worksheet function. In C2 as,

```
=howManySeconds(A2)
```

[image: regex_timevalue]

You should note that (by the right-alignment) those values are true numbers which can be totalled or otherwise mathematically manipulated. A custom number format mask of `0\s_)` has been applied to grant them a displayed *s* as a unit.

---

<sub>See [How to use Regular Expressions (Regex) in Microsoft Excel both in-cell and loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22542834/how-to-use-regular-expressions-regex-in-microsoft-excel-both-in-cell-and-loops) for an excellent local reference on using **Regular Expressions** in VBA.</sub>